# YouTube search API not filtering embeddable/syndicatable videos

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I'm embedding YouTube videos into an app I'm writing, but some of the results are videos that aren't allowed to be played on my site. I've tried setting both videoSyndicated and videoEmbeddable to true in the params but it doesn't seem to fix my problem.

[image]

```
const axios = require('axios');

    const ROOT_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';

    const search = (options, callback) => {
      if(!options.key) {
        throw new Error('Youtube Search expected key, received undefined');
      }

      const params = {
        type: 'video',
        videoEmbeddable: true,
        videoSyndicated: true,
        part: 'snippet',
        key: options.key,
        q: options.term,
      };

      axios.get(ROOT_URL, { params })
        .then((response) => {
          if(callback) { callback(response.data.items); }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    };

    export default search;`
```

Comment: An example search maybe and an example video which fails to play? And an example result set you got from your query? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: also, check if the video can be embeddable - [see these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=check+if+video+is+embeddable).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a copyright claim by a 3rd party, which happens outside of the YouTube API. You can check this separately by scraping the video page and searching for the copyright text.

Comment: This looks like a comment and not an answer to the question.

Comment: And yet it is true