# YouTube search API not filtering embeddable/syndicated videos

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Somebody already asked this question a year ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022634/youtube-search-api-not-filtering-embeddable-syndicatable-videos), but it didn't get much elaborated answers.

I'm trying to embed YouTube videos into my application. I use [YouTube Data API v3 - Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A2%2C%22q%22%3A%22weeknd%20in%20your%20eyes%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%2C%22videoEmbeddable%22%3A%22true%22%2C%22videoLicense%22%3A%22creativeCommon%22%2C%22videoSyndicated%22%3A%22true%22%7D) to search for videos to embed. To check if video is embbedable and syndicated, I set the videoEmbeddable and videoSyndicated parameters to *true* (as well as the type parameter to *video*). But this doesn't work most of the time.

For example, when I search for some random commercial song (e.g. Weeknd - Blinding Lights), the first result I get is some unofficial lyrics video [(this)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwxLwG2_Sxk), which is fine but can't be embedded into my application. Here's a screenshot of how it looks like when I embed it:[image]

I know this happens due to copyright issues, but is there a way to be sure if video can be played outside of YouTube?